# TYPO3 Extension output altered by TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 seems to alter the output of my Frontend extension.

Simple Testcase:

```
function main($content, $conf)
{
        $this->conf = $conf;
        $this->pi_setPiVarDefaults();
        $this->pi_loadLL();

        return '<a href="#test">test</a>';
}
```

When I call a page with this extension in the frontend i get:

```
<a href="pagename/?no_cache=1&action=show&id=3378#test">test</a>
```

Basically it prepends the path I used to access the page to the anchor link.
What could be responsible for this behaviour? RealURL?

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have somwhere in your TS template (in Setup) enabled prefixing:

```
config.prefixLocalAnchors = all
```

Note, that if you have set `config.baseURL=http://some.tld/` and enabled `RealURL` this is required, otherwise all anchor links will be redirected to the main page:

```
http://some.tld/#test
```

instead of

```
http://some.tld/pagename/sub/other-sub#test
```

Comment: thank you, thats it :) I simply created a template on the page where my extention will be which says: config.prefixLocalAnchors >

Comment: you better use `config.absRefPrefix` like the `realurl` manual suggests.